# External Guest receives individual Deny permissions as an owner with Full Control

Tags: sharepoint-permissions, external-users

We have a set of guest users (all from the same tenant) that are receiving individual Deny permissions that add up to denying everything on the site - they essentially keep getting circled back to the request access page no matter what level of access we give them. Has anyone seen this before? What causes a site owner with full control to receive all of these individual deny permissions?
[image]